# RegEx pagination in Url rewriting

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I use url rewriting on my site and have implemented code:

```
        r = new Regex(@"Default.aspx\?Buy=(?<1>[\w\-\+]*)(?:&amp;|&)+PageIndex=(?<2>[\d]*)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        txt = r.Replace(txt, "$1_dp.html?page=$2\"");
```

In that case my links are:

www.mydomain.com/computers_dp.html?page=0 [1,2,3] depends on page number.

Is it simple way by RegEx to check if page = 0 then don't add param ?page=0 and add it only if PageIndex is > 0.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused. You want to add ?page=0 if there is already ?page=1?

Comment: No, if PageIndex value is > 0 then should be page=[PageIndex], if PageIndex == 0, then page=0 should not be in the url

Comment: Where does PageIndex come from? I think you need more examples.

Comment: PageIndex is original url: mydomain.com/Default.aspx?Buy=computers&PageIndex=1 result should be mydomain.com/computers_dp.html?page=1 or mydomain.com/computers_dp.html if original is mydomain.com/Default.aspx?Buy=computers&PageIndex=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think this is the easiest way to solve this. Assuming the regex you have already implemented works, I would add another regex to simply replace `"?page=0"` with `""`.

```
r2 = new Regex(@"\?page=0$""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
txt = r2.Replace(txt, "\"");
```

There's really no way to check the value of captured groups within a regex, aside from really painful conditional lookaheads, so just adding another regex to cut out the corner case is the simplest, and therefore best solution.